# Why would wordpress not generate a debug log or output anything?

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a strange issue, the server is Apache with PHP 7.3, i have WP_DEBUG true, WP_DEBUG_LOG true , i also have my php.ini set to display_errors = on error_reporting = E_ALL and i also have the following in my wp-config.php

```
if(WP_DEBUG){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','on');
}
```

It's not making any sense, all i see is "There has been a critical error on this website" with no logs or output which isn't helpful. I also have no php.ini files in the doc root or any htaccess file at the moment that could be overriding those settings; it's also a completely fresh install of apache and php

Any ideas from anyone? By all rights i should be seeing the errors.

Comment: This is wrong. Use codex - https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: What are you talking about it's wrong? It's not wrong, it works perfectly fine like this on every other wordpress site just not this one, plus i already said i have the log and debug in wp-config as true

Comment: I stand corrected, having my own ini settings there was stopping it for some weird reason, normally works fine

Comment: Actually no it doesn't work, i managed to get a permission error to display with how i had it, but when that was fixed i still get a critical error message with no error log and no displayed errors, that's with just the wordpress constants WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG true.